# Is it necessary to implement async logging for ASP.NET MVC with log4net?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asynchronous, log4net

I saw a message queue like implementation of a logging class with log4net.

It's used for ASP.NET MVC web application, so I feel threads are already isolated. What's the benefit with this implementation?

```
public class Logger
{
    private ILog _logger;
    private static Logger _instance;
    private Queue<Action> _logQueue = new Queue<Action>();
    private ManualResetEvent _newItemsExist = new ManualResetEvent(false);
    private ManualResetEvent _terminate = new ManualResetEvent(false);
    private ManualResetEvent _waiter = new ManualResetEvent(false);
    private static object _syncLock = new object();

    private Thread _logThread;

    public enum LoggingType { Debug, Info, Warn, Error, Fatal };
    public Logger()
    {
        _logger = LogManager.GetLogger(
            System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);

        _logThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ProcessQueue));
        _logThread.IsBackground = true;
        _logThread.Start();
    }

    public static Logger Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if (_instance == null)
                lock (_syncLock)
                    if (_instance == null)
                        _instance = new Logger();

            return _instance;
        }
    }

    private void ProcessQueue()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            _waiter.Set();

            int i = ManualResetEvent.WaitAny(new WaitHandle[] { _newItemsExist, _terminate });
            if (i == 1) return;

            _newItemsExist.Reset();
            _waiter.Reset();

            Queue<Action> queueCopy;
            lock (_logQueue)
            {
                queueCopy = new Queue<Action>(_logQueue);
                _logQueue.Clear();
            }

            foreach (Action logAction in queueCopy)
                logAction();
        }
    }
    public void _LogMessage(string msg_, Exception inEx_, LoggingType type_)
    {
        lock (_logQueue)
            _logQueue.Enqueue(() => AsyncLogMessage(msg_, inEx_, type_));

        _newItemsExist.Set();
    }
    private void AsyncLogMessage(string msg_, Exception inEx_, LoggingType type_)
    {
        switch (type_)
        {
            case LoggingType.Debug:
                _logger.Debug(msg_, inEx_);
                break;

            case LoggingType.Info:
                _logger.Info(msg_, inEx_);
                break;

            case LoggingType.Warn:
                _logger.Warn(msg_, inEx_);
                break;

            case LoggingType.Error:
                _logger.Error(msg_, inEx_);
                break;

            case LoggingType.Fatal:
                _logger.Fatal(msg_, inEx_);
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with isolation. Whoever wrote this didn't want to wait for log4net to process the message. Although, buffering would reduce any delay. This code is *not* good though, because it forces you to use a hard-coded logger (and a singleton no less!) instead of using log4net's abstractions. This singleton in fact breaks isolation as it has to be shared across all threads

Comment: Also, .NET 4.5 has very good concurrent collections. There is no need to use Queue and locking when you can use ConcurrentQueue. That code has some serious issues

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need to implement any async logger for `log4net`, there is a very good implementation accompanied with a blog entry containing benchmarks and explaining the necessary details.

In summary, async is only half of the problem, you also need to provide batch logging to increase throughput otherwise flushing every log message one after another causes bottleneck on the thread main thread or otherwise.

You can find the library on [GitHub](https://github.com/NimaAra/Easy.Logger), [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Easy.Logger/) and the blog entry [HERE](http://www.nimaara.com/2016/01/01/high-performance-logging-log4net/).

Comment: Didn't mean that. I saw the singleton in the question, a manual thread, a Queue with locks instead of ConcurrentQueue and I think this implementation is rather scary. `Easy Logger` seems to create a properly asynchronous appender though

Comment: yes I agree, the class posted by OP has many issues and seems like a hack rather than a proper implementation of an appender or a forwarder.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos  Thanks a lot to both of you! Blog is very intuitive. Learned a lot from this question :)